# how to plot a graph using haskell graphViz

Tags: haskell, graph, plot, graphviz

I'm planning to draw a graph using Haskell graphViz. I'm  new to haskell, so this is quite difficult for me. Can someone show me a simple example ? I need a very simple example actually, so that I can understand it and use it in the scenario I'm working on

[image]

I get the above error on trying to install chart-cairo. I saw some examples on the internet and all of them requires chart-cairo. any idea how to resolve it ?

*EDITED"
The output that I get after executing the code  given by  https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827654/jamshidh
[image]

Comment: Please show us you put some effort in. Have you read the documentation for the Haskell library? Have you read the documentation for the GraphViz tools? What did you try after that? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: How about starting with trying to write graphviz by hand first with just a .dot file first? For a simple graph it's likely easier to just print out the .dot syntax from Haskell then using a library.

Comment: I edited my question. and mentioned the error that I get when trying to install chart-cairo. hope you guys help

Comment: Have you followed the instruction “`Please install ...`”?

Comment: Instead of Cairo, I actually tried something else. actually, someone else gave me this example. http://lpaste.net/97781 . but the problem is there's an error.

Comment: “there’s an error” is never helpful here...

Comment: You might find Brent Yorgey's 'diagrams' package easier, especially because there is a hosted paste instance at http://paste.hskll.org

Answer (score 11):

(This addresses your original question, described in the title, and doesn't go into the problems installing chart-cairo or chart, etc, which really should be spun out into different questions)....

The graphviz package includes some example graphs in module Data.Graph.Inductive.Example that can be used to get you up and running.  You can see the list of included graphs at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.3/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-Example.html....  I will use one called `clr479`.

Once you have a graph, you can convert it to an internal structure representing the dot format using `graphToDot`.  Note that you will need to supply some parameters, which are described in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.11.0.0/docs/Data-GraphViz.html.  Just to get up and running, I will use the supplied `nonClusteredParams`.

```
let graphInDotFormat = graphToDot nonClusteredParams clr479
```

Then, you will need to convert this to text suitable for input to the `dot` program.  You can do this with `renderDot . toDot`

```
let outputText = renderDot $ toDot graphInDotFormat
```

and, as usual, you need to convert text to string to use `putStrLn` (don't just use `show`, as it will include quotes and escape sequences, which `dot` will not understand)

```
putStrLn $ unpack outputText
```

Putting this all together, the final program createDotFile.hs would be

```
import Data.Text.Lazy
import Data.GraphViz
import Data.Graph.Inductive.Example
import Data.GraphViz.Printing

main = putStrLn $ unpack $ renderDot $ toDot $ graphToDot nonClusteredParams clr479
```

Compile using `ghc createDotFile.hs` (remember to cabal install the required packages, as well as graphviz itself if you want to do anything with the output).  On the commandline, you can now pipe the output of this program to `dot`, which will convert this to a usual format....  For instance, here I convert to svg

```
./createDotFile | dot -Tsvg > graph.svg
```

which on my linux box can be viewed by typing

```
eog graph.svg
```

[image: visualization of clr479]

---

Edit-

To clarify, the output of the haskell program needs to be provided as an input to GraphViz.  The msi file to install graphviz on windows here http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php.

Comment: First of all,would like to thank you because it runs without generating any errors. But the thing is I'm doing this on windows , not on Linux. So, do you know how I can view the graph ? I'll paste the output I get above in my question under something  called "EDITED"

Comment: According to the hackage description- "This is the top-level module for the graphviz library. It provides functions to convert Graphs into the Dot language used by the Graphviz suite of programs (as well as a limited ability to perform the reverse operation)."  So, according to this, the output of a Data.Graph program is another program that must be processed by the `dot` program, which is a part of GraphViz.  In other words, you will need to install GraphViz/dot on your computer and use that to create an actual graph (ie- as an svg).

Comment: I've added a link to graphviz for windows in the answer.  I've never tried it myself though....

Comment: great explanation, if i already have a dotgraph parsed 

(e.g. with `xDotText <- L.readFile "tempBdd.dot"  
let xDotGraph = parseDotGraphLiberally xDotText :: G.DotGraph String` ) how can i change (or replace) the parameters afterwards?