# How to plot graph labels with Haskell's graphviz package

Tags: haskell, graphviz

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20849893) question does not solve the problem that I'm facing, but my question is based on it.

What I'm trying to achieve is to plot a directed graph with labelled nodes and unlabelled edges using [graphviz](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz) package. In my case nodes have labels of type `String` (the type definition of the graph is `Gr String ()`). Here's the code (where used graph is a minified version of [clr486](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.7.0.2/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-Example.html#v:clr486) - a perfect example of my use case):

```hs
module Main where

import              Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph          (mkGraph)
import              Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree   (Gr)
import              Data.GraphViz                       (graphToDot, nonClusteredParams)
import              Data.GraphViz.Printing              (renderDot, toDot)
import              Data.Text.Lazy                      (unpack)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let exampleGraph = mkGraph (zip [1..3] ["shorts", "socks", "watch"]) [(1,2,()),(2,3,())] :: Gr String ()
    putStrLn $ unpack $ renderDot $ toDot $ graphToDot nonClusteredParams exampleGraph
```

It looks like the "labels" in context of `graphviz` haskell package don't mean what I'd assume are the actual labels of the graph - the resulting graph's labels turn out to be its "internal" indices. The output of this code is:

```
digraph {
    1;
    2;
    3;
    1 -> 2;
    2 -> 3;
}
```

And when passed to `dot` resulting graph looks like this:

[image: resulting graph]

But what I'd like to achieve is the following:

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try customizing your parameters. Something along these lines might work:

```hs
module Main where

import              Data.Functor                        ((<&>))
import qualified    Data.Text.Lazy as L                 (pack)
import qualified    Data.Text.Lazy.IO as IO             (putStrLn)
import              Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph          (mkGraph)
import              Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree   (Gr)
import              Data.GraphViz                       (graphToDot, nonClusteredParams, fmtNode)
import              Data.GraphViz.Attributes.Complete   (Label(StrLabel), Attribute(Label))
import              Data.GraphViz.Printing              (renderDot, toDot)

exampleGraph :: Gr String ()
exampleGraph = mkGraph (zip [1..3] ["shorts", "socks", "watch"]) [(1,2,()),(2,3,())]

labelledNodesParams = nonClusteredParams { fmtNode= \(_,label)-> [Label (StrLabel (L.pack label))] }

putGraph :: Gr String () -> IO ()
putGraph = graphToDot labelledNodesParams <&> toDot <&> renderDot <&> IO.putStrLn

main = putGraph exampleGraph
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. I've edited your code to be "compilable" : )

Comment: Hi, can you provide more explanation on how this works? Why are functors necessary?  The curly braces are for getting the fields of the record types, right? Then you set it to the labels from  example graph by using a lambda function?  Is there some documentation on why/how to set dotgraph arguments like this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Thanks for the fixes, mjarosie. :) @Daniel Miederna, functors are not necessary. putGraph could equivalently be written `putGraph graph = IO.putStrLn(renderDot(toDot(graphToDot labelledNodesParams graph)))`. The field fmtGraph is a function. I recommend finding the type of nonClusteredParams by looking it up on Hoogle, and then looking the type up on Hoogle to find documentation of the fields in the parameter record type. Does this information answer your question?