# How to change a node label when working with haskell's graphviz package

Tags: parsing, haskell, graphviz, dot

I would like to adjust the node labels of a dot graph while working inside a haskell program. Currently i can parse the graph and display the nodes but i dont know how to reach and change the 'attributes' of specific nodes, as indicated in the [haskell graphviz package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.20.1.0/docs/Data-GraphViz-Attributes-Complete.html). Below i included a relevant snippet of my code:

```
writeToDot d "tempTree.dot"
xDotText <- L.readFile "tempTree.dot"

let xDotGraph = parseDotGraphLiberally xDotText :: G.DotGraph String
L.putStrLn $ renderDot $ toDot xDotGraph
print $ graphNodes xDotGraph
```

giving for a simple tree example:

```
[DotNode {nodeID = "(nil)", nodeAttributes = [Label (StrLabel "1")]},DotNode {nodeID = "CONST NODES", nodeAttributes = [Style [SItem Invisible []]]},DotNode {nodeID = "F0", nodeAttributes = []}]
```

Now i would like to code something like a loop over these nodes where i adjust the label by adding 1 to its "integer value" name. I am a bit of an amateur still when it comes to both haskell and graphviz so i do not know how to interpret the graphviz documentation such that i can apply their methods.. Any help or an link of similar examples would greatly be appreciated!

A similar approach to define the parameters and then apply them when building the dot graph is shown in a stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000454/how-to-plot-graph-labels-with-haskells-graphviz-package?noredirect=1&lq=1), but i cant follow how, as no explanation is given.